# Angular passing variables to include file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

After searching and trying lots of things, I can't seem to find a solution to pass a scope object into a include file.

I have tried

```
<span ng-init="list_title = clients_list.title;
               list_subtitle = clients_list.subtitle;
               list_array = clients_list.clients" 
      ng-include="'/views/partials/lists/list_with_qty.html'">
</span>
```

and

```
 <span onload="list_title = publishers_list.title;
               list_subtitle = publishers_list.subtitle;
               list_array = publishers_list.clients"
       ng-include="'/views/partials/lists/list_with_qty.html'">
 </span>
```

and

```
<span ng-include-variables="list_title = publishers_list.title;  
                            list_subtitle = publishers_list.subtitle; 
                            list_array = publishers_list.clients" 
      ng-include="'/views/partials/lists/list_with_qty.html'">
</span>
```

they both pass through the object when called on the page by themselves.
However I am trying to include both of these includes one after another.

How can I pass through the variables so that the result isn't the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a directive with isolated scope and pass values as attribute.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? @AnandGargate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/M9cIxNfRIWA8gB41rx1Q?p=preview I have made directive with isolated scope. Replace your template with given list.html

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('listWithQty', function() {
  return{
    scope: {
        listTitle: '=',
        listSubtitle: '=',
        listArray: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'list.html'
  }
```